# PHP Application API Response Inconsistency (very random)

Tags: php, rest, networking, apache2, zend-framework2

We are experiencing a very odd and troubling issue with one of our PHP applications. The application uses ZF2, PHP 5.3, and Apache 2. The three attached screenshots represent the network data associated with three consecutive requests which are sent one after another in rapid succession. We always expect to get back application/json. When the app craps out, one of the requests will show content-type text/html. This is not a matter of specifying the response headers, because which api route returns the text/html content-type is variable.

Also note that the response that has content-type text/html will always have a content-encoding set to gzip (see first screenshot), whereas the successful request/responses will not have this set. The failing response will have empty response data (according to Chrome dev tools), although there is a content-length. There are also other minor differences: the request/response that fails will have a vary response header set.

This issue is pretty difficult to reproduce. Using a web browser, logging in clicking a view (to init api requests), then logging out, rinse and repeat until it bug appears (appearance rate is very random).

Has anybody experienced anything similar to this before? Any tips or suggestions are welcome. Thank you for your time.

[image: first request]

[image: second request]

[image: third request]

Comment: I would guess some sort of session race condition. Anything in the Apache error log?

Answer (score 0):

The responses where the Content-Type header is "text/html" is where PHP is having a fatal error, by default php.ini has display_errors set to off.  I am willing to bet if you turn on error logging if its not already on and look in your error log you'll see some fatal errors.